# Nginx redirects to default page after adding Lets Encrypt

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

Everything is working fine until I install Let's encrypt and modify /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

What is the mistake I'm doing

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;



        root /var/www/html;


        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name geekdashboard.com www.geekdashboaard.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-geekdashboard.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {        
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
}

}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem more fully, and detail the changes you made to move to SSL.  Also please supply and relevant access / error log entries. I also note that your "well known" directory is only on SSL - the first time you try to get a certificate there's no https, so I wonder if this works.

Comment: I followed this guide to setup SSL https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

Your `server` block hasn't got a `root` directive to tell nginx where your web site's files are located. Thus it serves the files from the default location, which are the sample files shipped with nginx.

To solve the problem, add a proper `root` directive in the `server` block.

Answer (score 0):

From snippets above, your root `root /var/www/html;` is pointing to the default nginx page. In case you have changed it and it still persist declare another root right below ;

---

`listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
 listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
 include snippets/ssl-geekdashboard.com.conf;
 include snippets/ssl-params.conf;`

to have

---

`listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
 listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
 include snippets/ssl-geekdashboard.com.conf;
 include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
 #new path
 root /path/to/your/project`